# How to automatically resize TStringGrid row

Tags: delphi

How to automatically resize TStringGrid row (DefaultRowHeight) to match the height of the font used?
I do something like

> Grid.DefaultRowHeight:= Grid.Canvas.TextHeight('X') + 4;

but it is not working. For small fonts, the height of the rows is way too big.

---

Update:

It seems to be actually a problem with program's logic. If I change the font multiple times, the current height of the row matches the size of the font from previous font change event (it is one step behind).

I use this code to intercept font's size change:

```
procedure TStrGrid.CMFontChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited; // let TControl react first
  DefaultRowHeight:= Canvas.TextHeight('ApApM')+ 4;
end;
```

It acts as if the procedure will be:

```
begin
  DefaultRowHeight:= Canvas.TextHeight('ApApM')+ 4;
  inherited; 
end;
```

(like first it changes the height, then it actually sets the correct font size - therefore the height is one step behind)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with this order: both the inherited `CMFontChanged` message handler and the `DefaultRowHeight` property setter call invalidate. It is due to the current font setting which is not yet updated:

```
procedure TStrGrid.CMFontchanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Canvas.Font := Font;
  DefaultRowHeight := Canvas.TextHeight('Ap') + GridLineWidth + 3;
end;
```

Explanation:

Invalidate only *flags* windows to repaint the window (the grid) somewhere in future. That happens certainly after obtaining the text height. As alternative you can call `Repaint` prior to the request for the new text height, but that would result in a double repaint, hence setting `Canvas.Font`.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to event ordering related issues then the easiest and quickest solution often was posting yourself a message via `PostMessage` (here from your `CMFontChanged` handler) and doing the update when receiving the posted message.

This has the advantage that it doesn't interfer with whatever the grids need to do to update its inner state.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Even though it is the best (and proper) I used NGLN's hack as it requires a single line of code :) Even if NGLN's hack requires an extra paint, it is ok since the font is changed rarely (if ever).

Comment: @Altar I would certainly not describe my answer as a _hack_, and it does not require an extra paint.

Comment: @Heinrich Your suggestion indeed solves many kind of these issues. But I just tested it, and it does not work for this situation. Pity.

Comment: @NGLN I just always fear side effects when changing the "thing" in the "thing change handler". But it seems to be a quick and efficient solution in this case. So why not :)

Comment: Well, it's not the "thing" I am changing here. I simply assign the "changed thing" to `Canvas.Font`. Setting `Canvas.Font` does nót trigger `CMFontChanged`.